# How to disable ssl connection for specific api calls on tomcat 8?

Tags: java, debian, tomcat8

I am setting up my tomcat 8 server to use a SSL connection and the application is working fine - the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS is good, but I need to find a way to allow HTTP for some pages (API calls).

Why do I need that? because those API calls are trying to upload/download something to/from the server and because the connection is secure, those files are firstly - encrypted, secondly - decrypted and finally - used. And because the CPU has low performance, the upload/download speed is very poor.

I've tried to change  configuration from conf/web.xml file, with no success.

If I change the  parameter from *CONFIDENTIAL* to *NONE*, but both connection types (HTTP /HTTPS) will be enabled - and this is not what I need.

Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Linux system like Ubuntu, then, instead of setting up an SSL connection setup in `Tomcat`, you will use the `Nginx` server. Use the following [link](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/) for installation.  In the Nginx server configuration file, `nginx.conf`, you can define a `location` inside the `server` name setting and then you can filter the APIs that you do not want to enable as `HTTPS`.

For setting `SSL` in `Nginx`, you have to use the `ssl_certificate & ssl_certificate_key` setting.